# How to draw gradient lines on ipad using monotouch framework

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

I am using "DrawLinearGradient" function to draw gradient line on ipad using monotuch framework. But the 2 colors that i am using are not dividing equally in the line.

```
CGColor[] colors = {UIColor.Red.CGColor,UIColor.Green.CGColor};
CGColorSpace colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();
float dWidth = 2*width;

float[] locations = {0.0f,0.5f,1.0f} ;
CGGradient gradient = new CGGradient(colorSpace,colors,locations);
ColorMessage.FontSize = width;
context.SetLineWidth(width);
context.SaveState();
context.Clip();
    context.DrawLinearGradient(gradient,penVertices[i],penVertices[i+1],0);
context.StrokePath();
gradient.Dispose();
colorSpace.Dispose();
context.RestoreState();
```

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: You have 3 locations but only 2 colors. * Cough * documentation * cough *

Comment: We are developing app in Monotouch framework. Can anyone please provide code that is supported in monotouch.

Comment: Look at the answer I linked to in the duplicate question.